# Button doesnt appear when using a pl/sql condition that takes an expression from another page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to define a condition to my button in the home page that is of type pl/sql expression in order to hide this button, if the specific text is not submitted from other users. The expression that im trying to return is a text field from another page(login).Here is my expression

:P101_PASSWORD='xxxxxx'

Here xxxxxx is the condition to show the button but the button doesnt appear whenever i log in as xxxxxx.

Comment: If the text field holds the user name why would you call it "P101_PASSWORD"?

Comment: Note that conditions are evaluated when the page is loaded; if the user enters data into the item the conditions are not re-evaluated. If you want to show a button when a particular value is entered, you can use Dynamic Actions. However, this doesn't make sense for a password field.

Comment: Sorry its displayed as password not text field.

Comment: If it's a password, it makes no sense to "interpret" it in any way, except to authenticate the user. Why would you look at the password to determine if someone's a manager or not? (that said, some managers could be identified as such by seeing what type of password they use, but that's another story...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly, it could be one of two reasons: item `P101_PASSWORD` receives NULL value just after login process or value of item with type "Password" couldn't be used in SQL and PL/SQL(I'm not sure that this was described in documentation).
You can try to make experiment (I can't do until morning). I don't know, what you want to do, but if you ask user to enter password once again, use verification function to check.

Comment: I want to just enable and disable my buttons in the home page based on specific users that logs in.

Comment: @ManHOOD It is better to use Authorization Schemes for that. But if you want Conditions, then select condition `Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2`, set `Expression 1` = `APP_USER`, `Expression 2` - your username.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is making the appearance of page items conditional on the name or group of the current user, querying the password field of your login page is most likely not the way you want to go (depending on your page processes, the session state of your page might get cleared after login. Also, if the user changes their password, you would need to update the display condition etc.).

The easiest way to handle this situation is probably to create a new group of users who should have access to the restricted information and functionality (call it PRIV_GROUP, for example). Next, define an authorization scheme of type 'PL/SQL Function Returning Boolean' with the following body:

```
BEGIN
  RETURN APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name => 'PRIV_GROUP');
END;
```

Finally, set your authorization scheme as the button's display condition.

**Edit:**

In your case, since you are using custom authentication, I would suggest you create an application level item to store the name of the currently logged user. Go to Shared Components -> Application Items -> Create and create an item called LOGGED_USER. 
Next, you need to create a post-authentication procedure: 
In your DB, issue the following command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE post_authentication IS
BEGIN
  apex_util.set_session_state('LOGGED_USER', upper(:P101_USER_NAME)); --Adapt to the name of your page item
END post_authentication;
```

To associate this procedure with your authentication scheme, go to Shared Components -> Authentication Schemes and edit your custom scheme. Under 'Post-Authentication Procedure Name', type "post_authentication" (without quotation marks).

If only user MANAGER should have access to the button, redefine your authorization (NOT authentication) scheme as follows:

```
BEGIN
  IF :LOGGED_USER = 'MANAGER' THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I have created a custom login authentication scheme that has many users and a manager. I need to enable that button only when the manager logs in to the page otherwise hide it if any other users logs in.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the setup of your authentication scheme? It shouldn't be a problem to adapt the authorization scheme to the specifics of your authentication scheme.

Comment: It's a custom authentication that's uses the user table that I have created .

Comment: I made a function that returns boolean holding 2 arguments, 1 for the username and 1 for the password. And it works fine when I choose it as my custom authentication scheme.

Comment: And how am I going to assign a value to this application item.